# Procedure to renew SSL certificate for custom java web server

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

Does anyone know the process to renew SSL certificate for custom java web server?

Comment: You're talking about a custom written web server as opposed to something like Apache or JBoss?

Comment: @BenV - Yes ..custom web server

Comment: What's the current setup?  A keystore file containing the certificate that is referenced by the web server through a config file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. We have keystore file and webserver references it. My other question is if I make the keystore file on local machine and put that on live server, will that work?? Or I have to make keystore file on server itself.

Comment: Have you been through http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/Security6.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would:

- request a new certificate
- import the new certification in the existing keystore under a new alias

  ```
  keytool -importcert -keystore key.jks -alias abc -file ABCCA.cer
  ```
- modify the server configuration accordingly
- remove the old certificate (once things are working)

  ```
  keytool -delete -alias abcold -keystore key.jks
  ```

Comment: Does alias play any role? Somehow I feel I have messed up with alias.

Comment: @yogsma It should (in your server configuration).